# How to add IPv6 route with systemd-networkd and select source address from limited subnet

Tags: routing, ipv6, systemd-networkd

#### TL;DR

In a systemd-networkd `.network` file, in the `[Route]` section, what do I put for the `PreferredSource=` option to make it select any available IP address as long as it's within a specific subnet like `fc00::/7`?

#### Details

I have a machine transmitting IPv6 multicast traffic, however I want the packets to originate from the IP address belonging to the internal network, not its global IP.  This is because the machines are firewalled and only allow packets in from internal IPs, so any multicast packets from a global IP are dropped.

The reason it is sending packets from the global IP is (I think) due to no particular source address being set in the routing rule, and the kernel happens to choose a global IP:

```
$ ip route get ff05::02
multicast ff05::2 from :: dev eth1 table local proto static src 2001:db8::1 metric 100 pref medium
```

Here I don't want it to send multicast packets from `2001:db8::1` but rather whatever IP address the machine has been assigned that sits within the `fc00::/7` "site local" subnet.

This route is set via systemd-networkd, so that I can specify which network interface multicast traffic should use to exit the machine.  I have done this with the following in a `.network` file:

```
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Route]
Type=multicast
# Send all multicast traffic out of this NIC.
Destination=ff00::/8
Metric=100
Table=local
#PreferredSource=  <-- what goes here?
```

If I use the `PreferredSource` address and put the machine's internal IP, then the source IP is set correctly and the internal IP is used for multicast traffic, which is exactly what I want.

However because I'm using IPv6 stateless autoconfiguration, and the `.network` file is shared among multiple hosts, I can't hard code the IP address in the `PreferredSource` parameter.

I need some way of selecting whatever IP address belongs within a particular subnet, and making that the source address - something like `PreferredSource=fc00::/7`.  Since you can't pass a subnet to this parameter, is there a way of doing this?